# Setting a user as an administrator via drush command line?

Tags: users, drush

How can I set a user to a specific role via drush? In my case I want to give the role of administrator to the user.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
drush help user-add-role
Add a role to the specified user accounts.

Examples:
 drush user-add-role "power user" 5,user3  Add the "power user" role to the accounts with name, id, or email 5 or user3, uids 2 
 --uid=2,3 --name=someguy,somegal          and 3, names someguy and somegal, and email address of billgates@microsoft.com       
 --mail=billgates@microsoft.com

Arguments:
 role                                      The name of the role to add                                                
 users                                     (optional) A comma delimited list of uids, user names, or email addresses.

Options:
 --mail=<me@example.com>                   A comma delimited list of user mail addresses of users to operate on. 
 --name=<foo>                              A comma delimited list of user names of users to operate on.          
 --uid=<3,5>                               A comma delimited list of uids of users to operate on.

Aliases: urol
```

So, for your use case:

`drush user-add-role administrator USERNAME`

Comment: tats too easy! =P ... at least now i know how to do it via sql... lol

Comment: @duckx but that's like using a back-scratcher to scratch your front