# Error When Changing User Role in Drush?

Tags: 7, users, drush

I wanted to see if there is a way to change a user role using drush. I found [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/169871/setting-a-user-as-an-administrator-via-drush-command-line) explaining how to do it but I get an error. I replaced the actual username with "USERNAME".

`drush user-add-role administrator USERNAME`

> ```
> > exception 'Drush\Role\RoleException' with message 'Could not find the
> > role:      [error] administrator' in
> > /usr/local/src/drush/lib/Drush/Role/RoleBase.php:46 Stack trace:
> > #0 [internal function]: Drush\Role\RoleBase->__construct('administrator')
> > #1 /usr/local/src/drush/includes/drush.inc(113): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
> > #2 /usr/local/src/drush/commands/core/role.drush.inc(273): drush_get_class('Drush\\Role\\Role', Array)
> > #3 /usr/local/src/drush/commands/user/user.drush.inc(281): drush_role_get_class('administrator')
> > #4 [internal function]: drush_user_add_role('administrator', 'USERNAME')
> > #5 /usr/local/src/drush/includes/command.inc(368): call_user_func_array('drush_user_add_...', Array)
> > #6 /usr/local/src/drush/includes/command.inc(219): _drush_invoke_hooks(Array, Array)
> > #7 [internal function]: drush_command('administrator', 'USERNAME')
> > #8 /usr/local/src/drush/includes/command.inc(187): call_user_func_array('drush_command', Array)
> > #9 /usr/local/src/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/BaseBoot.php(62): drush_dispatch(Array)
> > #10 /usr/local/src/drush/drush.php(70): Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()
> > #11 /usr/local/src/drush/drush.php(11): drush_main()
> > #12 {main}
> ```

I am using Drupal Commons 7.50 and Drush 7.0.0.

Edit: Things I have tried:

- spelling role correctly and making sure it exists
- clearing cache

Comment: Probably a stupid question but does the site definitely have an "administrator" role? Have you double-checked the UI/database to be sure?

Comment: Not a stupid question. Apparently we had the role named "administrators". Awesome, thanks!

Comment: Changed the command to administrators but still get the same error.

Comment: Well that's some sort of progress I guess :) Try clearing the cache just in case

Comment: No such luck. I edited my answer to reflect things things tried.

Comment: `Changed the command to administrators but still get the same error.` @Christia  Are you sure it's the same error? did you do `drush cc all`? Before doing your user add drush command, are you inside of your Drupal folder/directory (Ex: `cd /var/www/drupal`)?

Answer (score 1):

Syntax was wrong. It needed quotes and capitalization definitely matters.

`drush user-add-role "administrator" USERNAME`