# Migration after server crash: maintenance mode and/or cache problem

Tags: migrations, backups, maintenance-mode

I had a crash of my previous server and I tried to rise my website from the dead. I had backups of all the files & of the database (PostgreSQL). I was not the one who set up the website and my knowledge of Drupal is pretty low.
From what I understood/gathered, it is a 7.54 version and it runs with multisite.

What I did so far:

- Import my database backup in PostgreSQL (in the dumbest way possible: recreate the right database & user, import everything back in place);
- Upload all the files to my new server (running Debian Jessie);
- Give access to the `sites/` directories to `www-data` user;
- Clear the `sites/mysite/css/` and `sites/mysite/js/` directories;
- Disable CSS & JS aggregation (using `drush`).

I did the latest because the style of the website was broken; that was enough to revive it.

I still have on major issue: when I log in, I get the maintenance message. I therefore tried to disable `maintenance_mode` with `drush`; it didn't work.

I saw it could be related to cache issues; I therefore tried to clear the cache (once again with `drush` with `drush cc all`). It put the whole site in maintenance, and not only when I'm logged in.

I am not sure where the problem comes from. Any hint or suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you're logged in with admin (using default login form "sitename.com/user/login"), you can try switching the maintenance setting, and clear site cache by navigating to "admin => configure => development => performance"

Comment: @Yogesh I can't access the administration pages; when I log with a user with administrator rights, I still get stuck with the maintenance message.

Comment: Try logging in with user 1, if you don't have password for this user you can reset it using [this doc](https://www.drupal.org/node/44164). You should be able to do anything after logging in with user 1.

Comment: @Yogesh I changed user 1 password and logged in, but I still get the same issue. I check roles with `drush user-information {user1}` and it only has `authenticated user `; it seems to me that could be a problem.

Comment: you can try setting administrator role to user 1 using steps provided in [this ans](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/169874).

Comment: @Yogesh It just did that but I'm still stuck. Once logged in, I tried to access `http://example.com/admin/` but I got an Error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65122/discussion-between-yogesh-and-mbr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is finally how I solved the problem with Yogesh help: when I tried to access the admin section while logged in as an administrator, I got an error. I therefore checked the watchdog table. The `image_dimensions` table was somehow missing:

```
[...] Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "image_dimensions" does not exist [...]
```

I created the missing table, and everyhting was then working (access to the admin section, access to the user section and so on).